# GROUP BY on a dependent field

Tags: aggregate, group-by

Let's say I have a SELECT statement as follows:

```
SELECT ..., field1
  FROM ...
 GROUP BY field1
```

Now let's say I want to return a second field, `field2`. As it happens, field2 is [*functionally dependent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) on field1 (for example, field1 and field2 could be from the same table and field1 is the primary key of that table). I now have two equivalent ways to add field2 to the query:

Option 1:

```
SELECT ..., field1, field2
  FROM ...
 GROUP BY field1, field2
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT ..., field1, MIN(field2)  /* or some other, arbitrary aggregate function */
  FROM ...
 GROUP BY field1
```

Again, since field2 functionally depends on field1, both queries should return the same result set.

Are there any good reasons to prefer one option over the other?

Comment: Postgres [allows you](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) to project it anyway if it is functionally dependant on the group by columns. [as per the standard according to here](http://rpbouman.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be platform-specific. Although the results are the same, your performance might be very different.

I would suggest another approach, because it seems to clearly document the following intent: calculate some aggregates, then decorate them with another field(s). Here is an example:

```
WITH CustomerTotals AS(
SELECT CustomerID,
SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT Customers.Name, CustomerTotals.TotalAmount
FROM  CustomerTotals JOIN Customers 
  ON CustomerTotals.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
```

Comment: I think you've missed a GROUP BY from your CTE.

Comment: @dezso I did. Thank you for noticing, I fixed it.